# jqGrid special Sorting

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I have this data presented in a view with a jqGrid table.
It has a complex sorting order of rows done server side.

Now I need to be able to do some "free" sorting of the rows at the View.

By free I mean that the client needs to be able to move a row up or down to any place they want, skipping all the other sorting rules done at server.

Of course, this will need to be saved to the database later.

I thought that maybe add a column with an Up and Down arrow, that when clicked it will move the row to where it needs to be.

I'm not at my best with JavaScript, and I can't seem to find any examples of something similar to this anywhere.

Any tips on how could I approach do this? 
Or is there a better option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Sortable Rows](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#sortable_rows) feature built into the jqGrid.

You set it up with the following API call:

```
jQuery("#yourgridid").jqGrid('sortableRows', options);
```

It uses the jquery-ui Sortable widget for this so the optional options parameter can be used for any of the available options for the widget which you can find [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

For Example:

```
jQuery("#yourgridid").jqGrid('sortableRows', { cursor: 'crosshair' });
```

You can see a sample of this on the [Demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) page. (New in Version 3.6 -> Sortable Rows)

Comment: I know this feature, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I need to be able to sort arbitrarily, with no logic. I mean that the user should be able to move one row to any position. Something like the Drag & Drop but in the same table.

Comment: Dragging and Dropping in the same table is exactly what this is, I do not quite follow how this doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Brain fart / damage? Sorry, this is perfect.